# Unhide project from Project Dashboard in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have, out of curiosity I guess, clicked the little grey 'x' to the right of a project on my TeamCity Project Dashboard. It turns out that it hides the project from the dashboard.

And now I cannot find a way to 'unhide' it. When I try to use Configure Visible Projects menu, it says it's visible. Also if I hover over the downward arrow next to the Project link in the menu, I can navigate to the project.

But I really want to see it on the dashboard again.

Thanks.

Comment: And just as I post this I find the solution. Turns out it was the Build configuration that was hidden, and not the actual project. Configuring the that to be visible solved it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For those (like me) who struggled to find the configuration alluded to above:

1. Go to the main page (with the list of projects).
2. To the right of the project with the hidden build config there is a drop down that says "1 hidden". Use that to unhide it.

Comment: This was helpful for me but I was trying to un-hide a project configuration that had been deactivated and after reactivating the project it was still hidden. I had to copy the existing hidden build configuration which was then visible. I could then show the original hidden configuration as per this suggestion. (TeamCity 6.0.8)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, KevM, you saved my day. It looks like a flaw in TeamCity UI since there's no way to unhide build configuration if it's  the only one in a project.

Comment: KevM's solution above was what I needed - I had just one build config, and the "1 hidden" was not showing for me. Only after creating a second "dummy" build config could I unhide the original one.

Comment: If it's the only build configuration you can add a new one, show the original and delete the new one. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-16794

Comment: Problem is back in a later TC version reraised here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44218

Answer (score 1):

As a hack, you can get the request that's normally made to show a build configuration, but using a network console in the browser. You can (e.g.) install the Postman REST API client for Chrome and make that request manually, with the parameters for the build configuration that went missing.

POST to https://example.com/visibleBuildTypes.html with these parameters:

projectId=YOUR_PROJECT_ID
bt_visible:btXX (where XX must be replaced with the internal ID for the build configuration)
showOne:true (as opposed to hideOne:false to hide it)

ref: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-16794

Answer (score 1):

If you are hitting this from google in 2016 (or later...) like I did, this is a bug that has returned and the answer above doesn't help (unless maybe you are still on an ancient version of TeamCity).

To fix:

"... Go straight to the project page.  Add a (temporary) build configuration.  Go back to the overview page, and the project should be visible.  Now go to the down arrow next to the project name and unhide each of the build configurations.  Remove your (temporary) build configuration."

We are running on 9.1.1, and the above was also tested on 9.1.6.

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44218

Seems to be fixed if you upgrade to TeamCity 10.0.